# Sampling using common random numbers in r (efficiently!)

Tags: r, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Is there any way to perform sampling using common random numbers with `R`?

There are many cases where you do the following many times (for instance, if you wanted to plot Monte Carlo estimates at many different parameter values). First, you sample, say, ten thousand variates from a normal distribution, and second, you take the average of some function of these samples, returning a single floating point numbers. Now, if I wanted to change a few parameters, changing either of these two functions, I would have to re-do those steps over and over again.

The naive way would be to sample fresh draws over and over again using some function like `rnorm()`. A less naive way would be to use a different function that takes a large collection of common random numbers. However, if I used this approach, there might still be a lot of copying going on here, due to `R` mostly using pass-by-value semantics. What are some tools that would allow me to get around this and avoid all this copying in the second situation?

Comment: It is possible to use pass-by-reference semantics in R by using environments (perhaps `new.env(parent=emptyenv())` or `local({...})`) instead of `list`s or such (`R6` does this, I believe). I don't know what you mean by *"common random numbers"*, though.

Comment: One such use is done in [`opencpu::req`](https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu/blob/221ab997d49811a3ef1fb63c2ecb4bff0de3fcf8/R/req.R), from which I have adopted and adapted the technique several times myself. This is one of several mechanisms one could use to have a ("hidden") cache or state that is preserved across calls.

Comment: @r2evans this is statistical jargon. For instance if I wanted to sample from normal distributions in many different ways, I could sample once from a "standard normal" with mean 0 and variance 1, and then appropriately scale and shift elements of the random vector that I have. It reduces the variance/std.dev/dispersion quite often.

Comment: *"this is statistical jargon"*? If you sample with `X <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=0)` and later want that based on `mean=10` and `sd=3`, then ... `X*sd+mean`. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question or the intent of it. When you tag the question with `pass-by-*`, you suggest a CS-centric discussion, not a statistics-based one. Further, your question *"what are some tools"* is smack-dab within *recommend or find a book, tool, software library*, specifically [off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Perhaps you can make your question a bit more concrete/specific?

Comment: @r2evans you are correct that I am not interested in discussing the statistical aspect of this goal. Your previous comments seem relevant and could be extended into an acceptable answer. So I doubt that we will get to recommending textbooks

Comment: To that last point: I don't want to belabor the "on-topic" rules to a "T", but many other questions on SO are effectively treating this site like a human-curated search engine, which is neither its intent nor efficiency. I don't mind basic recommendations, as long as there is a good starting point. Not all questions need to have code to start with. I think I understand why you started your first comment with *"this is ..."*, I see your point. So while my answer below does answer the statistical component of it, I think the main take-aways are `environment`s and *"verify it is worth it"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking two types of questions here:

1. Programmatically, can we preserve a large pull of random data in such a way that side-steps R's default pass-by-value?
2. Mathematically, if we make a large pull of random data and pick from it piece-meal, can we arbitrarily change the parameters used in the pull?

The answer to 1 is "yes": pass-by-reference semantics are possible in R, but they take a little more work. All of the implementations I've seen and played with are done with `environment`s or non-R-native objects (C/C++ pointers to structs or such). Here is one example that caches a large pull of random "normal" data and checks the pool of available data on each call:

```r
my_rnorm_builder <- function(deflen = 10000) {
  .cache <- numeric(0)
  .index <- 0L
  .deflen <- deflen
  check <- function(n) {
    if ((.index + n) > length(.cache)) {
      message("reloading") # this should not be here "in-production"
      l <- length(.cache)
      .cache <<- c(.cache[ .index + seq_len(l - .index) ],
                   rnorm(.deflen + n + l))
      .index <<- 0L
    }
  }
  function(n, mean = 0, sd = 1) {
    check(n)
    if (n > 0) {
      out <- mean + sd * .cache[ .index + seq_len(n) ]              
      .index <<- .index + as.integer(n)
      return(out)
    } else return(numeric(0))
  }
}
```

It is by-far not resilient to hostile users or other likely mistakes. It does not guarantee the length of available remaining random numbers. (To put in checks like that would slow it down below a threshold of reasonable-ness, with the benchmark in mind.)

Demo of it in operation:

```r
my_rnorm <- my_rnorm_builder(1e6)
# starts empty
get(".index", env=environment(my_rnorm))
# [1] 0
length(get(".cache", env=environment(my_rnorm)))
# [1] 0

set.seed(2)
my_rnorm(3) # should see "reloading"
# reloading
# [1] -0.8969145  0.1848492  1.5878453
my_rnorm(3) # should not see "reloading"
# [1] -1.13037567 -0.08025176  0.13242028
# prove that we've changed things internally
get(".index", env=environment(my_rnorm))
# [1] 6
length(get(".cache", env=environment(my_rnorm)))
# [1] 1000003

head(my_rnorm(1e6)) # should see "reloading"
# reloading
# [1]  0.7079547 -0.2396980  1.9844739 -0.1387870  0.4176508  0.9817528
```

Let's make sure that the random-number scaling of `sigma*x+mu` makes sense by starting over and re-setting our seed:

```r
# reload the definition of my_rnorm
my_rnorm <- my_rnorm_builder(1e6)
length(get(".cache", env=environment(my_rnorm)))
# [1] 0
set.seed(2)
my_rnorm(3) # should see "reloading"
# reloading
# [1] -0.8969145  0.1848492  1.5878453
my_rnorm(3, mean = 100) # should not see "reloading"
# [1]  98.86962  99.91975 100.13242
```

So to answer question 2: "yes". Quick inspection reveals that those last three numbers are indeed "100 plus" the numbers in the second `my_rnorm(3)` in the previous block. So just shifting "normal" random numbers by mu/sigma holds. And we did this while still using the large pre-pulled cache of random data.

---

***But is it worth it?*** This is a naïve test/comparison in and of itself, constructive suggestions are welcome.

```r
t(sapply(c(1,5,10,100,1000,10000), function(n) {
  s <- summary(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    base = rnorm(n),
    my   = my_rnorm(n),
    times = 10000, unit = "ns"
  ))
  c(n = n, setNames(s$median, s$expr))  
}))
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
# reloading
#          n   base    my
# [1,]     1   1100  1100
# [2,]     5   1400  1300
# [3,]    10   1600  1400
# [4,]   100   6400  2000
# [5,]  1000  53100  6600
# [6,] 10000 517000 49900
```

(All medians are in nanoseconds.) So while it would have seemed intuitive that "smaller pulls done more frequently" (with `rnorm`) would have benefited from this caching, I cannot explain why it is not very helpful until pulls 100 and greater.

Can this be extended to other distributions? Almost certainly. "Uniform" would be straight forward (similarly scale and shift), but some others might take a little more calculus to do correctly. (For instance, it is not obvious without more research how the "t" distribution could alter the degrees-of-freedom on pre-pulled data ... if that's even possible. Though I do count myself a statistician in some ways, I am not prepared to claim yes/no/maybe on that one yet :-)

Comment: There seems to be a constant overhead for `n < 100`. I find it surprising that the overhead for these two very different functions is so similar.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to r2evans' answer concerning **is it worth it?**: I don't think so, since instead of caching random draws one could also use a faster RNG. Here I am adding `dqrnorm` from my [dqrng](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dqrng) package to the comparison:

[image]

- `dqrnorm` is the fastest method for `n <= 100`
- for `n > 100`, caching and `dqrnorm` are comparable and much faster than `rnorm`